# Android localization resources

Tags: android

I have just finished developing an android application that I was asked to make. I had also planned to translate it in different languages; below you can see the **tree** of the folders/files:

[image]

Inside `strings.xml` there are all the values that I am using inside the classes and they are all in Italian, my language ([Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qxby.png) you can see an example if needed). I'd like to be able to translate all those fields in English and french as well.

I have read this article -> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

From what I have understood, I'd have to create a folder called `values-fr` with a `strings.xml` inside (it will have the same values names, but different translations).

**QUESTION**

I would like to be able to support English and Italian as well, but I don't understand how to manage the folders. Could you please tell me which option is the correct?

1. Inside the folder `values` use `strings.xml` with Italian (my language) strings. Then create another folder called `values-en` and, like I did before, create `strings.xml` with English values
2. Inside the folder `values` use `strings.xml` with English strings. Then create another folder called `values-it` and then, create `strings.xml` with Italian values

I guess that the point **2** is the correct solution but I'm not sure. The folder `values` has English as default language?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: both are valid. values/ is the fallback. Decide what's your fallback and be consistent.

Comment: So if I kept values in italian and I created values-en (with its relative strings.xml), it would be correct?

Comment: yes, there is no rule that enforces you in keeping the english file into values/

Comment: Ok thank you, got it :) Could you post an answer? so I can upvote

Comment: like the way you have asked a question. Properly formatted and properly described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking both are valid. `values/` is the fallback if a more specific qualifier is not found. There is no written rule that enforces you in having the English strings in `values/`. It just makes a little more sense to have the English as fallback since it easier to find foreigners that speak English rather than Italian

Comment: Yes, I have thought the same. I am using values/ in English because it's more known that italian. I will create a values-it/ and values-fr/. Thank you! :)